# Dirac explained spin 1/2 with ribbons and ropes - is there another way? (With answer by Roger Penrose himself - probably)

Tags: quantum-spin, fermions, topology

[image: Dirac's visualization]

Dirac used chairs, ropes and scissors to explain spin 1/2. Is this visualization *unique*?

Or is there any other method to show that 2 rotations and 0 rotations are similar, but 1 rotation is not? (Arms instead of belts do not count as something different...)

**Addendum:**

The question is for some system that realizes a rotation in 3d, instead of anything using belts and ropes. Do all such realizations have "connections to the outside or to the walls"? Or are there simpler realizations?

Comment: Have you ever seen the classic holding a mug upright in your hand and spinning your arm around twice demonstration? [Like here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8q7yM69GX4).

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWlk1gLkF2Y&ab_channel=PBSSpaceTime) (at about 9:30s in) shows an animation of a cube with ribbons.

Comment: Where is this picture from?

Comment: I suspect that the picture is from Penrose's book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider representing a rotation using a vector, where the vector's direction represents the rotation axis, and its length represents the rotation angle. The zero vector represents the identity. Because rotations are periodic, a vector of length $\pi$ radians in one direction represents the same rotation as the vector of length $\pi$ radians in exactly the opposite direction. So the unique rotations make up a (solid) sphere with radius $\pi$ centred on the origin, with antipodal points identified. That is, they are considered the same point, so the world 'wraps around', and a curve passing out of the sphere in one direction reappears coming back in at the opposite point.

Now, consider the orientation 'trajectory' of an object undergoing some rotation considered as a dynamic process. The vector representing it traces out a continuous curve through the sphere, potentially passing out one boundary and entering again at the antipodal point, potentially multiple times. A rotation coming back to its starting point traces out a closed loop.

If we consider a diameter of the sphere, this represents a $360^\circ$ rotation about a fixed axis. Now, it doesn't matter how we stretch and distort the trajectory, if we start from the diameter, crossing the outer sphere at one point (remember, antipodal points are *the same* point), then the result always has to cross the sphere at an odd number of points. Whenever we push a piece of the curve across the boundary sphere, *two* intersections are created or destroyed. In particular, this means that we can never shrink the loop to a point.

However, if we thread the sphere *twice*, by passing along the diameter two times in the same direction, then we have an even number of crossing points. We can take one  of them, slide it around the sphere without breaking or tearing the loop, and make a loop where we pass along the diameter one way, then reverse course and come back across the sphere in the opposite direction. This loop *can* be continuously shrunk to a point at the origin. Looping around the sphere twice along one axis is a $720^\circ$ rotation.

It comes down to what you mean by 'a rotation'. In one definition, we only consider the initial and final states of the object being rotated. A 'rotation' maps directly from the initial orientation to the final orientation, with no thought of what route it takes to get there. This is rotation as a transformation. But we can also consider 'rotation' as a dynamic process; a trajectory through 'orientation space'. And the trajectory-type rotations come in two topologically distinct classes, with either an odd or an even number of boundary crossings, that *cannot* be continuously transformed into one another.

Dirac's belt trick is just a concrete realisation of this continuous trajectory. Moving along the belt, the orientation of each small section is continuously connected to the orientations of its neighbouring sections. So the belt in some configuration represents a continuous trajectory through 'orientation space', and deformation of the belt represents continuous distortion of the trajectory curve. It turns out that there are two distinct classes of configuration that cannot be transformed into each other, but the $720^\circ$ rotation is of the same class as the identity.

Because the identification of antipodal points is a bit brain-bending, another way of thinking about it is as a *projective space*, where we think about *straight lines through the origin* as our 'points'. We map a line segment onto a semicircle, a disc onto a hemisphere, and a ball (as described above) onto a hemi-3-sphere. Each straight line intersects the hemisphere at one point, and the same line passes through both end points simultaneously - they are both identified with the same line. Then we can easily see that the lines representing antipodal points are naturally connected. But we find that this way of thinking has a bonus, in that it lets us keep track of odd and even classes, by considering the straight line to have an orientation - an arrow on it pointing in a particular direction. For the purposes of representing a rotation-as-mapping, the two line orientations are indistinguishable. But for the purposes of tracking the odd or even number of crossings, the arrow points towards *the other hemisphere* every time it crosses the boundary, and so we can consider the straight-line-with-arrow to be an object that changes sign when the rotation it represents (that only perceives the unmarked straight line) turns through $360^\circ$.

And thus we can find a much simpler pair of objects with this sort of relationship. A straight line through the origin appears to return to its original state after a $180^\circ$ rotation, but if it is secretly an *oriented* straight line, it has to be rotated *twice* as much. We can use the $180^\circ$ rotation of an unmarked straight line to projectively *represent* rotations of $360^\circ$, but then that means the *oriented* line represents something that needs a $720^\circ$ rotation to get back to where it started.

I'm not sure that it helps all that much when it comes to understanding spinors intuitively, but it answers the question here, that yes, there are other methods for attempting to illustrate it besides Dirac's belt trick.

Comment: This kind of visualization represents the set of all rotations in an abstract space, and it is well explained. I was looking more for some system that realized a rotation, like belts and ropes, in 3d. Do all such systems have "connections to the outside"? Are there simpler realzations?

Comment: All the best in the Royal Society!

Comment: I suspect that this was Penrose himself - thank you for your time!

Comment: I was a bit slow to get it, but Stackexchange can be proud to have had Roger Penrose as a visitor here.